# How do I properly use --override parameter of tfx extension create or tfx extension publish

Tags: json, windows, tfs, command-line-interface

I'm trying to override the 'version' field of vss-extension.json when publishing my extension, but can't get the `--override` parameter to work.

I can get `overrides-file` to work like this:

`tfx extension create --overrides-file override.json`

where `override.json` contains one line:
`{"version": "0.0.9999"}`

But when I try it with `--override` like this:

`tfx extension create --override {"version": "0.0.9999"}`

I get this:

> error: Error: Failed to parse JSON argument override. Info:
>   SyntaxError: Unexpec ted token v in JSON at position 1

I've tried various things, like adding single-quotes outside the curly braces, or omitting the curly braces but I get similar errors.

I am using version 0.5.4 of the "TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tfx extension create --override "{\"version\": \"0.0.9999\"}"`